# Is there software or code that is used to simulate hot ion plasma?

Tags: resource-recommendations, computational-physics, simulations, software, plasmon

How are hot plasma simulated like fluid particles in CFD?

Note: If this question is topic, i will eventually delete question but i only need an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The controlled-fusion community has been developing CFD simulation code for plasmas, for decades. This is an extraordinarily difficult task because each computational cell's pressure, temperature, magnetic field, heat exchange, electrical current, etc. has to be tracked, which makes it very, very computationally intensive.

Note that this code is also used by fusion bomb designers, which means much of it is the property of the defense establishment, and you and I can't get access to it.

Finally, note that even if there were open-source plasma simulation code available, you would probably need a state-of-the-art supercomputer with a FORTRAN compiler to run it on.